# How to invoke/simulate request to any url of application inside of application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How can I invoke a request to any url (controller/action) of my Rails3 application inside of application?

I've tried to use `app` object (Application) with `get` method, but it works only from console and not in the application.

***For example***: I have a controller that could handle all requests.  It is not configured in `routes.rb` and this controller could parse the `request.uri` and return HTML in accordance of request. I need to get this html inside of application in other controller.

Comment: So what you want is basically to redirect request to another controller?

Comment: When redirecting i cannot get the response. In my case i will to get the response from action of another controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking for is the [component feature](https://github.com/rails/render_component) that was officially removed from Rails in 2008 because it was slow and leads to bad design practices.

You can try to reproduce the feature, if you really need it. Or you can perform a new HTTP request internally (using a HTTP client) to the second location, get the response and then return the result.

Comment: Thank's! Will do it via HTTP client. Is it normal design practice in this case or not? How can i prevent such situations in future? (Maybe exists another design solution for it? Generally it should a page previews like previews in google search)